# How to delete Missing archive log file

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, recovery

I’d needed to stop archive log mode for some reason.

When I tried to change the mode message told me to some file have been missing.

```
Alter database noarchivelog;

ORA-01111: name for data file 5 is unknown - rename to correct file

ORA-01110: data file 5: 'C:\APP\JAC484\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\MISSING00005'


SQL> select FILE#,ERROR from v$recover_file where FILE#=5;

FILE# ERROR

---------- ------------------------------------------------

 5 FILE MISSING


SQL> select file_id ,file_name from dba_data_files where file_id in (select FILE
    # from v$recover_file where ERROR like 'FILE MISSING' and FILE# = 5);

FILE_ID

----------

FILE_NAME

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

5

C:\APP\JAC484\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\MISSING00005
```

I’d like to recover or delete above `MISSING00005` file.

However, there isn’t any physical file.

Does anyone know how to operate?

I've already `delete archivelog all`; from RMAN.

Comment: Strange message. Are you in Mount State?

Comment: Hi, any news on your issue ?

Comment: Nothing has been changed. Also, I can mount and I can even open without any error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Il looks like you (or someone else) deleted the file n°5 BEFORE you were putting DB in noarchivelog.
You have to restore this file from a previous backup and recover it to the time you stopped the DB for your operation.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t backup this file. I can’t recover by this way.

Comment: Ouch ! Try follow [this](https://www.pythian.com/blog/how-to-recover-a-subset-of-an-oracle-database/)

Comment: And maybe restore an older backup on another machine, extract via datapump the missing data, but if the missing file is member of a multifile tablespace, I don't think you would be able to restore.

Comment: I didn't do your way.However I have been to able to change 'archivelog' mode to `noarchivelog' mode as I wanted.

Comment: Could you please describe what you've done ? For passing by people's enlightment.

Comment: A was able to change `noarchivelog` mode.However,the problem wasn't solved. There was still `MSING00005`  in the controle file and I wasn't able to do any `SQL` statment. I gave up to recover.I re-installed Oracle and re-create table spaces and tables.